# mapping throught nodeList

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

So, i have a issue using map(). 
I dont know why but i got only last listning.

```
let myOptions = {};
const getList = test=> some.current.querySelectorAll(test);

//that will generete nodeList
const list = getList('.list-for-test a');
```

so if i map that like that (i got all the listening):

```
Array.from(list).map((e) => console.log(e))
```

but if i would like to add some data from my collection  like that:

```
Array.from(list).map(el => myOptions= {...myOptions, ...{'html': e.innerText, 'href': e.href)
```

and

```
console.log(myOptions)
```

will give me only last output...

Any idea where i make a mistake?

What i need to achieve:
1. Collect data
2. Pass data

```
<>
{content ? {myOptions.map((e) =><importedElement href={e.href} html={e.html}/>)} : <Component {...props} />}
</>
```

Comment: A variable can only hold a single value. Each iteration assigns a new value to `myOptions`, so after the last iteration, `myOption` has the value set in the last operation. It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve with the assignment in the callback. If you want to create a new object for each node, then just return the object from the callback and assign the return value of `.map`: `let result = ...map(el => ({'html': e.innerText, 'href': e.href}))`.

Comment: What are you trying to get as a result here?

Comment: The spread operator overrides the `html` and `href` properties on each iteration. What is the desired output? How the `myOptions` should look like?

Comment: my option will be set of data that i will pass to create new element.  but befere passing them i have to collect them.

Comment: Why are you using an object instead of an array ?

Comment: Then you need an array. Check out the Viktor's answer below for a hint and example

Comment: collecting all data depends from passing value

Answer (score 0):

`myOptions` is only one variable, with one value. Every time you assign it, it overwrites the previous value. Just do `.map(el => {...myOptions, ...{'html': e.innerText, 'href': e.href)` if your trying to make a list. Im assuming `myOptions` was defined before the `.map`. Map loops over a given array, and builds a new array that is the result of what is returned from each array. I think your issue is you are trying to use it like `each`. For example

Given an array:
`var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

`var newArr = arr.map((val) => val + 1)`

This loops over each value, adds one and returns that value to the new array, which is returned by the map method and stored in `newArr`.

If you really want to do it the way you're doing it, you need to make `myOptions` and array and push values into it. Which would look something like this:

`var myOptions = []
list.forEach(val => myOptions.push({'html': e.innerText, 'href': e.href})`

But you should just use map.

EDIT: So based on your edit you need to do this:

```
const getList = test=> some.current.querySelectorAll(test);

const list = getList('.list-for-test a');

list = list.map(elem => {'html': elem.innerText, 'href': e.href})
```

Just to clarify

Comment: "*This is the difference between declaring a variable with var and let*" - no, `var` vs `let` has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Your right. I was thinking he was doing something else. Wasn't really sure where he declared the variable

Comment: Realized he was probably declaring the value outside of the loop and treating it like for each

Comment: @Viktor If you're not sure about the problem or the solution, it's generally better to ask for details in the comments rather than posting an answer based on your assumptions

Comment: Ahh well technically the answer was still correct. The assumption at the beginning was incorrect. And I apologize for that. The issue though was still that he was over writing the variable as appose to pushing it into an array or just using map as intended. @SebastianKaczmarek